# Search for pattern and use results in new search query

Tags: python, search, tree

I have the following problem that I'm looking for some help with please. I am running some json query that returns results which I've formatted to look like this.

```
World,Europe
Europe,Italy
Europe,Germany
Germany,Munich
Germany,Frankfurt
```

The first column provides the parent and the second column provides the child. The idea is a user will provide the child as a search string and what I need to do is build a python list that first searches for the parent of the child. The parent value is stored and we will now becomes the search criteria to see whether it's a child and it's own parent will be returned until we traverse all the way to the top Node and so on until we get to World which has no parent.

I know World will always be the final parent so that can be used as some sort of placeholder if it helps. What I'd like is to have a situation where my final list will contain these elements, if for instance I searched for Frankfurt.

```
searchresults = ['Germany','Europe','World')
```

and if it was Italy

```
searchresults = ['Europe','World')
```

In a sense part of my problem is I'm not sure what in Python I need to start with this as I get stuck at the second search passthrough. As always, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First process the data:

```
data = """World,Europe
Europe,Italy
Europe,Germany
Germany,Munich
Germany,Frankfurt"""

M = dict( tuple(reversed(line.split(','))) for line in data.split('\n') )
```

That results in this dictionary:

```
>>> M
{ 'Europe': 'World',
  'Germany': 'Europe',
  'Italy': 'Europe',
  'Frankfurt': 'Germany',
  'Munich': 'Germany' }
```

From that one can simply follow the dictionary from a given item to its parent until the top is reached and accumulate the path with this:

```
def path(loc):
    result = [loc]
    while loc != 'World':
        loc = M[loc]
        result.append(loc)
    return result

print path('Germany')
print path('Italy')
```

Which prints:

```
['Germany', 'Europe', 'World']
['Italy', 'Europe', 'World']
```

Note that if `loc` doesn't exist, `KeyError` will be raised.

You could allow any parent-less item to terminate the path successfully by changing:

```
    while loc != 'World':
        loc = M[loc]
```

To:

```
    while loc in M:
        loc = M[loc]
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a simple solution:

```
worldList= [];
worldList+= [["World","Europe"]];
worldList+= [["Europe","Italy"]];
worldList+= [["Europe","Germany"]];
worldList+= [["Germany","Munich"]];
worldList+= [["Germany","Frankfurt"]];

finalList= [];

currentPlace= "Frankfurt"; #we suppose this is the user choice

sizeLength= len(worldList);
i= 0;

while i<sizeLength and currentPlace!="World":
    if worldList[i][1]==currentPlace:
        finalList+= [worldList[i][0]];
        currentPlace= worldList[i][0];
        i=0;
    else:
        i+= 1;


print finalList
```

output:

['Germany', 'Europe', 'World']

Answer (score 0):

You can start the search in your array and if there is a hit, the parent of that child you can save it in the final array. Then start the search again but this time searching for the parent as a child.